# How to override the CMD command in the docker run line

Tags: cmd, docker, dockerfile

How you can replace the cmd based on the docker documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

You can override the CMD command

Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod +x /srv/www/bin/* & chmod -R 755 /srv/www/app
RUN pip3 install -r /srv/www/app/pip-requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/srv/www/bin/gunicorn.sh"]
```

the docker run command is:

```
docker run --name test test/test-backend
```

I tried

```
docker run --name test test --cmd ["/srv/www/bin/gunicorn.sh"]
docker run --name test test cmd ["/srv/www/bin/gunicorn.sh"]
```

But the console say this error:

```
System error: exec: "cmd": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The right way to do it is deleting cmd ["..."]

```
 docker run --name test test/test-backend /srv/www/bin/gunicorn.sh
```

Answer (score 12):

The `Dockerfile` uses `CMD` instruction which allows defaults for the container being executed.

The below line will execute the script `/srv/www/bin/gunicorn.sh` as its already provide in `CMD` instruction in your `Dockerfile` as a default value, which internally gets executed as `/bin/sh -c /srv/www/bin/gunicorn.sh` during runtime.

```
 docker run --name test test/test-backend
```

Now say if you want to run some thing else, just add that at a end of the `docker run`. Now below line should run `bash` instead.

```
docker run --name test test/test-backend /bin/bash
```

Ref: [Dockerfile Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Answer (score 4):

For those using docker-compose:

`docker-compose run [your-service-name-here-from-docker-compose.yml] /srv/www/bin/gunicorn.sh`

In my case I'm reusing the same docker service to run the development and production builds of my react application:

`docker-compose run my-react-app npm run build`

Will run my `webpack.config.production.js` and build the application to the `dist`. But yes, to the original question, you can override the CMD in the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **Dockerfile**

```
CMD ["sh" , "-c", "command && bash"]
```