# Dockerfile - Adding CMD to a docker image with RUN if else

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a use case where I would like to not add CMD to the image based on the argument passed when building the image.

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t ${npm_package_version} . --build-arg arg=test
```

if the argument is `test`, then I do not want to add the CMD layer to the image, snippet from the `Dockerfile`,

```
RUN if [ "$arg" = "test" ] ; then CMD yarn test ; fi
```

But this throws the error below,

```
/bin/sh: CMD: not found
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How can I add `CMD yarn test` only if the arg is `test`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Docker statements can't be done conditionally. You can do shell commands conditionally in a RUN statement, where the condition is handled by the shell. But CMD isn't a shell command, so you can't do that.

Comment: Having a `CMD` that you override at `docker run` time isn't harmful and I'd just leave the line in.  (It's often considered a best practice to use an identical image in all environments, and not rebuild the image when you promote it from test to production for example.)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I will leave that CMD there and will override it while running the container as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979783/how-to-override-the-cmd-command-in-the-docker-run-line)